# Error: Freestyle Lines Ignoring Displacement

Tags: displacement, freestyle

I have been trying to get my animations to have a hand-drawn look and wanted to make my models  slightly wiggle with procedural displacement on each frame. I also want to outline each object, so I am using freestyle lines.

To try this, I made a little test and applied the displacement to a cube and unfortunately, the freestyle lines do not touch the cube.

I am using cycles and have the "displacement only" setting active. I have the freestyle line settings set to select creases. When I try to render an image with this, the freestyle lines appear where the creases of the model would be if I had not used displacement.

[image: Here is the result I ended up with]

The Blender version I am using is version 2.82.

I am wondering if I may be doing something wrong. I haven't found many talking about this online, so I hope at least someone has the solution. I just really hope this isn't an unavoidable bug.

Comment: If you bake your displacement as a mesh, then I'm sure it will display freestyle correctly. Here's a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the displacement node in the shader editor isn't very good with freestyle lines. I just found out about a displacement modifier in the modifiers tab that actually changes the geometry itself, so I'll use that instead.